# How to use simulcast with webrtc android sdk?

Tags: android, webrtc

(I am newer of stack overflow user and sorry for my poor English.)

I am using WebRtc Android SDK to create a chat app, and our team decides to use
simulcast to deal with various abilities of participants. However, when I come to the SDK APIs, I can not find a way to use simulcast.

I use the SDK with offical-recommended manner:

implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'

(The concrete version is 1.0.28513.)

I have googled much and found some code fragment like this:

```java
RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit transceiverInit = 
new RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit(peerConnectionParameters.transDirection, mediaStreamLabels
                      /*, encodings*/ // cannot create Encoding instances
              );
...

peerConnection.addTransceiver(MediaStreamTrack.MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, transceiverInit);
```

However, when I try to create Encoding instances，I found the Encoding's constructor cannot be accessed, it is package access limit.

By the way, I have tried using reflection to forcibly create Encoding instances.
But it will cause an error when this code executes as might have been expected:

```java
peerConnection.addTransceiver(MediaStreamTrack.MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, transceiverInit);
```

I have also gone through the SDK APIs, and cannot find any other way to set up the simulcast.

So how should I use simulcast with webrtc android SDK?

Comment: Hi @yanshu. did you found answer how to create "Encoding instances"?

Comment: @VadimEksler They have fixed the problem, please update the version